# Can touch api be used to create custom touchpad events for windows 10?

Tags: c#, windows, touch, touchpad

Have been looking to try and create some custom events for the windows precision driver touchpad on windows 10, have seen many old forums saying that it isn't possible, however I have read that touch api includes the touchpad, is that true?

If not are there any good drivers that can be worked on in order to create custom events? Only app on windows that I have seen modify the touchpad events is multiswipe, is there any idea how they were able to do that?

Thank you